# Android- Dexopt error

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-studio

I make project in Android studio use some .so files.
I made a mistake and  I changed the .so files in my project. I have similar project in eclipse and I copy the .so files to the Android studio lib jnilib and this is the meseege I get:

```
 installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error) in order to procceed, you hava to uninstall the existing application
```

I remmember that when I import the project to Android studio it do something with them maybe it related..

If someone knows it will be very helpful.

I tried all the wipe thing.. I dont it related in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to import the .so file with the tools of android studio and dont copy the file. I think that when I imported it with android studio tools it added some lines to gradle file.